# how not show application on the desktop at startup

Tags: vb.net, startup

I am trying to build application which is show form when a user clicks on it but not when the windows started up like many applications that run in the background without showing gui on desktop for example, how  application can recognize when a user clicks on application and when  windows startup do that?
I tried notifyicon and other things but did not help so any reference to the tutorial or help is welcome.

How did I hear  I need to build a service application or application with the installation, is that correct?

Comment: Just add a process argument at startup (for example `-silent`) and don't show the form if that arg is present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minimize app at windows startup - visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582139/how-to-minimize-app-at-windows-startup-visual-basic) (replace `Me.Close` with `Me.Hide` if you don't want to close your form completely).